# How to calculate electric potential distribution of nodes in subgrid using FDM?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, computational-physics, simulations

Boundary: the potential of the upper electrode is 7 V, and lower is 0. Potential of two edges is shown in the following figure.
[image]
It is easy to calculate the potential distribution of nodes using Finite Difference Method with Laplace' equation. But when adding subgrid (the red grid of the following figure), how could I calculate the potential of subnodes? Thank you, guys.
[image]

Comment: Do you understand how to do it in the case of the top image?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos  Oh, yes, when using 2nd order accurate FD approximation, I could calculate the case in the upper figure. So should I use 4th order accurate to sort the case of the second figure? Expecting some details. Many thanks.

Comment: Each of those 4 smaller squares should average to one of the larger squares. So you kinda have 2 domains to solve: one is a $6\times7$ block the other a $2\times14$ block. Just apply the same discretization & scheme to both domains, but for the larger you'll need to average the values of the smaller domain.

Comment: This is a sort of "static mesh refinement" ([outline here](https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/athena-public-version/wiki/Static-Mesh-Refinement)), which is a looser form of adaptive mesh refinement (which I discuss in [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/371228/25301)).

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Right, I got some of it. But I am confused that how I could calculate nodes at the interface, namely the nodes at 3rd row. Thanks for patience.

Comment: I would break the third row down into another refined line (so you have $4\times14$ domain) using equivalence (all 4 subnodes are equal to parent node) and use simple averaging for use on larger domain. Left & right boundaries can probably be obtained using linear extrapolation.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Thanks. So I could divide the 7×7 grid into 3 part: 2×14 subgrid, 6×7 grid and 1 refined line at 3rd row, and calculate them respectively, right? For two domains, use Vij=1/4(Vij-1+Vij+1+Vi-1j+Vi+1j), and for the interfacing line, use Vij=1/2(Vij-1+Vij+1), do I? I am purblind to do it... I have to make sure the first step is correct for potential calculation since I will consider some more complicated case as some conductors existing in the bonds. Thanks for your help.