# Looking for more details on an adaptive mesh refinement (AMR) algorithm

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

The clustering algorithm of Berger and Rigoutsos 1991 (*IEEE Transactions on Systems, Man, and Cybernetics*, vol. 21, No.5, Sept/Oct 1991) gets alot of use, it seems.  I would like to try implementing it, but I find the discussion of the algorithm to be rather sketchy in a couple of important places.  Does anyone know of a more full explanation of this algorithm?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370315/25301

Comment: Also, it might be useful for you to mention what it is about Berger & Rigoutsos' discussion you find to be sketchy, that way someone here might be able to find a better way of explaining it.