# Books and review articles for numerical relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations

What are good books or review articles to read for numerical relativity?

I have read some textbooks on the 3+1 formalism (such as the book by Baumgarte and Shapiro), but I would like to have a comprehensive understanding of the major developments and breakthroughs in this field so far. Additionally, I would like to know what are the current frontiers and areas of focus in this field, including any subfields.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370315/2451

Comment: What results have you turned down when searching "numerical relativity review article" in your favorite search engine and/or arXiv?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos:  But I have difficulty finding out where to stray from. So I used the tag resource-recommendation.

Comment: *...where to stray from* Do you mean "where to start from"? Or that you get distracted when finding something?

Comment: Sorry. It is 'start'.

Comment: For review articles, just find the most recent one. Using Brave search, I found one from 2020 as the top result of the aforementioned search (which even cites the book you've read).

Answer (score 1):

I've not read them myself, but from what I've heard, Baumgarte's two books on numerical relativity are pretty much the standard texts on these matters. I've been told that they're very comprehensive and easy to follow.

If it's the 2010 one that you read, then I recommend checking out the 2021 one. Obviously it will be more up-to-date with developments since the 2010 version was published.